# Is it possible to use a diet app to calculate the time of impact of a comet?

Tags: realism, dont-look-up

Kate, a character, states that a comet will hit Earth in six
months, ten days, two hours, 11 minutes and 41 seconds,
causing the extinction of all life:

> Prof Mindy: When did you do those calculations?
>
> Kate: I put the moment of impact on a diet app. So, impact is when my
> diet ends.

Is it possible to use a diet app to calculate the time of impact of a comet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You misunderstand. She didn't calculate it *on the app*, she calculated it on the whiteboard at the centre with Dr Mindy and later had it confirmed by Dr. Oglethorpe at NASA ("6 months and four days"). Later on she inputted that number into her diet app which apparently has a rolling countdown function.

As you can see from [the script](https://assets.scriptslug.com/live/pdf/scripts/dont-look-up-2021.pdf), it's just a simple timer.

> INT. KATE’S DIET APP
>
> CLOSE UP of KATE’S DIET APP
>
> countdown showing 5 days, 3 hours, 48 minutes and 11 seconds until
> diet ends.

He's astounded by the [amazing accuracy of her calculation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_joke#:%7E:text=A%20museum%20visitor,eighteen%20days%20ago.%22) (down to the second), but in reality it's just that the app is counting from an arbitrary point.